# Vizier of the Menagerie and cost reducing

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a cost reduction on generic mana, can [Vizier of the Menagerie](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vizier%20of%20the%20Menagerie) help reduce non generic mana costs?

For example, I have [Animar, Soul of Elements](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Animar%2C%20Soul%20of%20Elements) in play with 2 +1/+1 counters on it, can Vizier help to cast the coloured part of a creature spell, for example could I play [Strangleroot Geist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Strangleroot%20Geist) for free?

Answer (score 8):

No.

Vizier of the Menagerie does not modify the cost; it allows mana to be treated as other types of mana for the purpose of paying the cost. The cost of Strangleroot Geist is still {G}{G}, which is not reduced by Animar, Soul of Elements.

For comparison, [Kentaro, the Smiling Cat](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kentaro%2C%20the%20Smiling%20Cat) does give an alternative cost, and that cost could be reduced by Animar, Soul of Elements all the way to {0}.

Comment: I understand it doesn't change the cost, but if I can pay {2} for the Geist it may be reduced by Animar.

Comment: @sinsedrix Vizier *doesn't* turn the cost of {G}{G} into {2}. It's still a cost of {G}{G}. The only thing that's changed is how you pay that symbol.

Comment: @sinsedrix In other words: cost reduction, as the term implies, only applies to *costs*, not payments. As you already understand, the mana costs of a spell don't change with Vizier, therefore Animar can not reduce the amount of colored mana costs either.

Answer (score 4):

This is more a question about Animar, Soul of Elements than it is about Vizier. Animar's cost reduction ability affects generic mana, and only generic mana. If your Animar has two +1/+1 counters on it, then if you have a 2GG card, the cost becomes GG. If you have a 1GGG creature, the cost becomes GGG. Animar does not affect the colored mana requirements.

After the cost reduction, Vizier lets you spend other colors of mana on the cost. So for example the cost of a 1GGG creature becomes reduced to GGG, which you can spend RRR on if Vizier is in play. But you still need to spend three mana.